# TestSuite Execution Order in Maven

Tags: maven, junit

My unit tests are incremental. That is, each test tests one particular function but there is dependency on the functioning of previous tests....perhaps not orthodox, but it is robust.

Within a test suite, tests are ordered by the order provided in the @Suite.SuiteClasses annotation.

Maven (surefire plugin), seems to order test suites in alphabetical order:

```html
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  <configuration>
   <includes>
    <include>**/ModelTestSuite.java</include>
    <include>**/ServiceTestSuite.java</include>
    <include>**/ZFlowTestSuite.java</include>
   </includes>
   <additionalClasspathElements>
   <additionalClasspathElement>${webinf.dir}</additionalClasspathElement>
   </additionalClasspathElements>
   <systemPropertyVariables>
      <log4j.configuration>file:${l4j.test}/log4j.test.properties</log4j.configuration>
   </systemPropertyVariables>

  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

If I want FlowTestSuite to run after ServiceTestSuite, then I rename it ZFlowTestSuite.

This works but it feels like a hack. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: The first thing is why this feels like a hack, cause you don't have unit tests. These are called integration tests, cause they are not independent. And using separate suites does usually not make sense in relationship with unit tests.

Comment: Yes, that is the conventional answer and I genuinely recognize the merits of this answer. There are also reasons for doing it incrementally. However, I doubt either of us want to get into a deep discussion on this. Specifically, I'm interested in whether suites can be ordered  in a more  organized manner but I infer from your answer tat they can't be

Comment: That is not a conventional it is the real answer, cause this shows you are doing things wrong apart from that you can of course use the configuration of [maven-surefire-plugin runOrder option](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder) which gives you the possibility some things..but the only chance i see to really make the order by your own definition simply define a global suite which contains the other suites. Or just name the suites similar like `010-XXX`, `020-XXX` etc..

Comment: Both are great suggestions. Thanks a million. As for the distinction between conventional use of a tool and wrong use of a tool, I will agree to differ.